# Code optimization for null or empty check

Tags: c#, .net, performance, optimization

Hi I am checking **datatable** row value. If the value is not null or empty then checking for the value if it is a number. Otherwise add in to the error list. If the value is null or empty then assign null.

The code is working fine but I want to check if there is any better way to do this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

here is my code.

```
if (!(row.IsNull("limit") || row["limit"].ToString().Length == 0))
{
    //Check if value is number
    if (int.TryParse(row["limit"].ToString().Trim(), out n))
    {
        query.limit = Convert.ToInt32(row["limit"].ToString().Trim());

    }
    else
    {
        errorList.Add("limit: Value:" + row["limit"].ToString());
    }

}
//if value is null then assign null
else
{
    query.limit = null;
}
```

Comment: you could write - "query.limit = n;" in place of "query.limit = Convert.ToInt32(row["limit"].ToString().Trim());" to avoid double parsing

Comment: Just for future reference: Questions where you have working code, but are looking for possible ways to improve it, are a better fit on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few points I have to mention here:

- By using `int.TryParse` to parse the `row["limit"]` you will get the converted value in the out parameter, then you need not convert the same again to an integer using `Convert.ToInt32`, use the out parameter instead.
- The first `if` can be simplified using NullConditional operators(`?.`).
- There may be chances for getting `row` as null, in such cases, you need to check for `null` before accessing `row["limit"]` otherwise NullReference will be the result

I think it will be more clear and simple if you do like this:

```
if (row != null && row["limit"]?.ToString() != "") // means row["limit"] definitely has some value
{
    int currentLimit = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(row["limit"].ToString().Trim(), out currentLimit))
    {
        query.limit = currentLimit ;   
    }
    else  
    { 
        errorList.Add("limit: Value:" + row["limit"].ToString());  
    } 
}
else
{
    query.limit = null;
}
```

If you are not using c# 6 then `row["limit"]?.ToString()` will not work in this case you have to use the condition as like this:

```
  if (row != null && row["limit"] != null && row["limit"].ToString() != "")
```

Comment: This assumes C# 6 . Also it is usually safer to leave even single line clauses in brackets.

Comment: @BradfordDillon : yes It is `c# 6`, i have updated the answer

Comment: You don't need to initialize `currentLimit` to `0`. Using it as an `out` parameter guarantees it to be filled with *something*. In the case of `int.TryParse` with either the correctly parsed (converted) integer as you said, or `0` (`default(int)`) if anything went wrong.

Comment: @BradfordDillon I agree single lines should be within braces.

Comment: For the first checking you can try if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))

Comment: @Shaahin: no this wont works, How it give value of `row["limit"]`

Comment: @un-lucky, so you can put limit as index like: if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["limit"]))

Comment: Then `row["limit"]` will throws the exception if `row` is null @Shaahin

Comment: @un-lucky, No, I put ! before the condition, it means if it is not NullOrEmpty

Comment: @Shaahin: hope that you ware misunderstand the scenario that I'm saying, consider the code that you supplied ie., `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["limit"]))` also consider that `row` is null, then accessing something(`["limit"]`) from null will throws exception even if it is inside `IsNullOrEmpty`, Still it is not clear means could you please make a try?

Comment: @un-lucky, yes you have to check for the raw as well, my intention was focusing on  ["limit"] column, you can do like this:
 if(rw != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw["limit"].ToString())